# Flutter - How to upload a file?

Tags: flutter, dart, web, file-upload

```
                try {
              var token =
                  'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1laWQiOiIyIiwibmJmIjoxNjc5MzEzMzI5LCJleHAiOjE2NzkzMTUxMjksImlhdCI6MTY3OTMxMzMyOX0.5NFFiQjrmD39dK6IRMkb6UBTSgozNUoca8IXpKv6dlI';

              ///
              var request = http.MultipartRequest(
                'POST',
                Uri.parse("http://xxxx/api/FileUpload/UploadFile"),
              );
              Map<String, String> headers = {
                "Authorization": "Bearer $token",
                "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
              };

              for (var event in events ?? []) {
                ///

                final reader = html.FileReader();
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event);
                final bytes = await reader.onLoad.first;
                print('${bytes.total} bytes loaded');
                var file = reader.result as Uint8List;
                var multipartFile = http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('file', file);
                request.files.add(multipartFile);
       }
                request.fields
                    .addAll({"facility_id": "46", "module_id": "3263", "id": "1"});
                request.headers.addAll(headers);
                print("request: " + request.toString());
                var response = await request.send();
                print("This is response: " + response.toString());

                if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                  print('File uploaded successfully');
                } else {
                  print('Error uploading file: ${response.reasonPhrase}');
                }
              }
```

Error in response:
"Null is not a subtype of type InstanceRef in type cast"

I can't figure out what is causing this

Comment: Which line is it complaining about?

Comment: var multipartFile = http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('file', file);